# Saving data to device using Parse array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, pdf, download

My application pulls data from a Parse class called PDFTableView and stores the name of file and author to my tableview. I programmed it so when a user picks the cell they get taken to downloadDetailView where they can download the file my push of a button. Everything else works but i don't know how to program the button to save the file stored in my array onto a computer. here is my code

this is my segue from tableview that sends the "PDFFile" to download page

```
 detailVC.downloadfile=[[PDFArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"PDFFile"];
```

this pulls the file into the detail view. Property declared in detail view.h

```
@property (retain,nonatomic) PFFile * downloadfile;
```

and in implementation i have the button created and would like it to save the PDF file on the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a ton of different ways of doing this. The easiest is probably to do this in your button TargetAction:

```
NSData *data = [self.downloadfile getData];
[data writeToFile:@"/path/to/save.pdf" atomically:NO];
```

Using this method will happen synchronously though, so it'll hold up the main thread if you don't dispatch it async, or use the PFFile's asynchronous methods.

Comment: Umm i receive no errors but file doesn't download. I do get Warning: A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug. Probably like you said because it is synchronously done. My log for Download file does get initiated but file doesn't show up on desktop.

Comment: I don't want to go through the whole asynchronous method seems long winded for PDF files.

Comment: You'll have to do something if you don't want it to run synchronously, and you really should do any downloading on a background thread. Check to see if the NSData object that gets returned has any data in it, then check to make sure your path is set up right.

Comment: So i use this method now it gets rid of the warning but file still doesn't show up on desktop: -(void) Savefile {
    
        [self.downloadfile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {

            }
            else if (data) {
                [data writeToFile:@"/Users/Danny/Desktop" atomically:NO];
               
                NSLog(@"Downloading...");
            }
        }];
    }

Comment: You have to add a filename. Try something like /Users/Danny/Desktop/ParseDownload.pdf

Comment: That worked! I had it already working I'm trying to figure out now how to download each file without the previous one being replaced. Because when I add the file name previous one gets lost. Someone mentioned to use filedoesexist method and create a loop…I have no idea how to do that lol

Comment: or i mean Fileexistsatpath method